# How can I completely remove something from a Mercurial repository?

Tags: mercurial, repository, bitbucket

If you see here, you'll see that I have:

```
CheeryTomatoe.Examples  <--- I want to remove this.         
CherryTomatoe           
CherryTomatoe.Examples
```

https://bitbucket.org/sergiotapia/cherrytomato

How can I completely remove this from my repository? What command can I run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, you can edit the history (provided nobody has yet cloned your public repo), as described in:

- [Mercurial FAQ 4.14 and 4.15](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FAQ#FAQ.2BAC8-CommonProblems.I_committed_a_change_containing_nuclear_launch_codes.2C_how_do_I_delete_it_permanently.3F)
- Mercurial Wiki "[Editing the History](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/EditingHistory)"

However, that is not the best way to work with Mercurial, so what you did in [your third commit](https://bitbucket.org/sergiotapia/cherrytomato/changeset/9299008ef69e) is better: **`hg rename`**:
See Hg book: "[renaming file](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/mercurial-in-daily-use.html#id364064)":

> When you use the hg rename command, Mercurial makes a copy of each source file, then deletes it and marks the file as removed.

Answer (score 3):

It is your initial commit.

Delete the repository and start over.

Comment: Actually it seems I figured it out. Still don't know how this was upvoted if it doesn't give the answer. In the future if people have this question, a 'start over' isn't good enough.

Comment: But it is the right answer. You have nothing to lose by starting over, you have no repository history. If you start out on the wrong foot, go one step back and try again, that *is* the right answer.

Comment: If, on the other hand, you want to keep the flawed initial commit, you just delete the folder, commit it, and move on, as with any other change you might perform. Was that your question, how to delete something from the repository? The "completely remove" was probably what threw @sylvanaar and me off, because usually, in terms of (D)VCS, "completely remove" usually means obliterate from history.

Comment: I guess it was not clear to me why you would want to preserve the history of the incorrectly named folder when it was just the first changeset in your repository - unless the question was more academic in nature.